# Chrome mouseover reacts to invisible content outside div border but inside box-shadow region

Tags: css, google-chrome

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/marvmartian/t79kn/

Mouseover the gray box to the right, moving past the bottom border and into the box-shadow region.  In Chrome, there is a mouseenter event on (invisible and supposedly clipped) "item 5".

Removal of the box-shadow line:

```
box-shadow: 21px 19px 39px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

makes everything work perfectly again.   Firefox doesn't have the issue.  Is there something bad I'm doing that's causing this, or is this a Chrome bug?

Comment: I would say it's a bug.

Comment: I have concluded that it is a Chrome bug as well.  Thanks for looking, @vals.  It's easy enough to work around, and the workaround is harmless:  if ($element.offset().top > $container.offset().top + $container.height()) { return false; }